# populating a second select box after selecting a first select box value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need to select second select box value only after selecting the first select box.I want to insert these values into database.. My view page is below.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Country</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="edu" onChange="EduBackgrd()" name="country">
                        <option value="">Select</option> 
                        <option value='India'>India</option>
                        <option value='United States'>United States</option>
                        <option value='United Kingdom'>United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value='Canada'>Canada</option>
                        <option value='Singapore'>Singapore</option>
                        <option value='Others'>Others</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Location</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="edct" name="location">
                    <option value="">Select</option>

                    <script>
    var eduBak = {};
    eduBak['India'] = ['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Chennai', 'Kolkata', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabade', 'Pune'];
    eduBak['United States'] = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];
    eduBak['United Kingdom'] = ['England', 'Northrn Ireland', 'Scotland', 'Wales', 'other'];
    eduBak['Canada'] = ['Alberta ', 'Brirish Columbia', 'Manitoba', 'others'];
    eduBak['Singapore'] = ['Singapore','others'];
    eduBak['Others'] = ['Others']

    function EduBackgrd() {
        var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
        var model = document.getElementById("edct");
        var educ = edu.options[edu.selectedIndex].value;
        while (model.options.length) {
            model.remove(0);
        }
        var ed = eduBak[educ];
        if (ed) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < ed.length; i++) {
                var e = new Option(ed[i], i);
                model.options.add(e);
            }
        }
    } 
    </script>
</select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

To insert into database I tried my model as:

```
public function insert()
{
$data=array(
'Country'=>$this->input->post('country'),
        'Location'=>$this->input->post('location'),
        );
$this->db->insert('tbl_employer', $data);
        }
```

I'm getting a number while inserting.. I don't know how to set value attribute in the script which I had written for selecting the second select box..How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) for this like,

```
$(function(){    
    $('#edu').on('change',function(){
       $.ajax({
          url:'php-page.php', // php page to get options
          data:{q:this.value},// passing the value
          success:function(data){
             $('#edct').html(data);//append options
          }
       })
    });
});
```

Your `php-page.php` should look like,

```
<?php
    $eduBak=array();
    $eduBak['India'] = ['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Chennai', 'Kolkata', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabade', 'Pune'];
    $eduBak['United States'] = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];
    $eduBak['United Kingdom'] = ['England', 'Northrn Ireland', 'Scotland', 'Wales', 'other'];
    $eduBak['Canada'] = ['Alberta ', 'Brirish Columbia', 'Manitoba', 'others'];
    $eduBak['Singapore'] = ['Singapore','others'];
    $eduBak['Others'] = ['Others'];

    $q=isset($_REQUEST['q']) ? $_REQUEST['q'] : '';
    $str='';
    if($q){
       $arr=$eduBak[$q];
       if(!empty($arr)){
           foreach($arr as $val){
               $str.='<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>';
           }
       }
    }
    echo $str;
    exit;
?>
```

UPDATE: Below is the example of without using `PHP`

```js
var eduBak = {};
eduBak['India'] = ['Delhi', 'Mumbai', 'Chennai', 'Kolkata', 'Bangalore', 'Hyderabade', 'Pune'];
eduBak['United States'] = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];
eduBak['United Kingdom'] = ['England', 'Northrn Ireland', 'Scotland', 'Wales', 'other'];
eduBak['Canada'] = ['Alberta ', 'Brirish Columbia', 'Manitoba', 'others'];
eduBak['Singapore'] = ['Singapore', 'others'];
eduBak['Others'] = ['Others']

$('#edu').on('change',function() {
  var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
  var model = document.getElementById("edct");
  var educ = edu.value;
  while (model.options.length) {
    model.remove(0);
  }
  var ed = eduBak[educ];
  if (ed) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < ed.length; i++) {
      var e = new Option(ed[i], ed[i]);
      model.options.add(e);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Country</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="edu" name="country">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value='India'>India</option>
      <option value='United States'>United States</option>
      <option value='United Kingdom'>United Kingdom</option>
      <option value='Canada'>Canada</option>
      <option value='Singapore'>Singapore</option>
      <option value='Others'>Others</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Location</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="edct" name="location">
      <option value="">Select</option>          
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
194:294 Uncaught ReferenceError: EduBackgrd is not defined

Comment: Rmove the onchange from first select and bind it using on(), see my updated answer without using PHP.

Comment: It is inserting the position of element in the array not its value.

Comment: Yes, because of  `Option(ed[i], **i**`) use `Option(ed[i], ed[i])` instead